# Having trouble with file path in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm having trouble with the path of a certain file. It actually works fine on Mac OS, but when I run the same chunk of code on Ubuntu, it throws this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/Desktop/Numeratti/pg2dm-python-master/ch2/BX-Dump/BX-Book-Ratings.csv'

I've written the script in sublime-text and I run it from terminal (ubuntu)

```
def loadBookDB(self, path=''):
    """loads the BX book dataset. Path is where the BX files are
    located"""
    self.data = {}
    i = 0
    #
    # First load book ratings into self.data
    #
    f = codecs.open(path + "BX-Book-Ratings.csv", 'r', 'utf8')
    for line in f:
        i += 1
        #separate line into fields
        fields = line.split(';')
        user = fields[0].strip('"')
        book = fields[1].strip('"')
        rating = int(fields[2].strip().strip('"'))
        if user in self.data:
            currentRatings = self.data[user]
        else:
            currentRatings = {}
        currentRatings[book] = rating
        self.data[user] = currentRatings
    f.close()
    f = codecs.open(path + "BX-Books.csv", 'r', 'utf8')
    for line in f:
        i += 1
        #separate line into fields
        fields = line.split(';')
        isbn = fields[0].strip('"')
        title = fields[1].strip('"')
        author = fields[2].strip().strip('"')
        title = title + ' by ' + author
        self.productid2name[isbn] = title
    f.close()
    #
    #  Now load user info into both self.userid2name and
    #  self.username2id
    #
    f = codecs.open(path + "BX-Users.csv", 'r', 'utf8')
    for line in f:
        i += 1
        #print(line)
        #separate line into fields
        fields = line.split(';')
        userid = fields[0].strip('"')
        location = fields[1].strip('"')
        if len(fields) > 3:
            age = fields[2].strip().strip('"')
        else:
            age = 'NULL'
        if age != 'NULL':
            value = location + '  (age: ' + age + ')'
        else:
            value = location
        self.userid2name[userid] = value
        self.username2id[location] = userid
    f.close()
```

I would like to know why this is happening. The problem is that I cannot load the dataset. I think that it has to do with file paths in linux cause when I run the same script via terminal on MAC OS, it loads the dataset perfectly.

Thank you!

Comment: Your paths are going to be different between operating systems. Desktop files often reside in `/home/<user>/Desktop` in Ubuntu.

Comment: to get the file path in ubuntu , go the the file directory in terminal and then type , `pwd` you will get the current working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem

1.

Try to locate your file in the filebrowser, right click on it -> Properties -> copy the location, append the filename.

In linux filenames usually start with `/home/<username>/...` or short `~/...`

2.

If you are working with python in a terminal you can use

```
>>> import os
>>> cwd = os.getcwd()
>>> my_dir = os.path.join(cwd, "my_dir")
```

3.

If you do not have a filebrowser only a terminal you can use `cd <dir>` to move around your filesystem and `ls` to locate your file and if you found it use `realpath <file>` to print out the entire filename.

Comment: you can use `pwd` in working directory in terminal ubuntu to get full directory  path

Comment: In terminal (ubuntu) I construct an instance of the recommender class:   `r = recommender `, then I call the method with its path (which I got from draggint the file into the terminal iteself) ` r.loadBookDB('/Desktop/Numeratti/pg2dm-python-master/ch2/BX-Dump/') ` . But it does not seem to be working. I keep getting the same error!

Comment: See again your path does not start like `/home/<username>/...`